# Emulate keyboard

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010

How can I emulate keyboard in application running in background (hidden in tray).
I want to press, hold, and relase keys on keyboard programatically.
Also, I would like to move mouse around and be able to click.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SendInput API](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendinput) function

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the [Windows.Forms.SendKeys API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx)

Here is a How-To: [How to: Simulate Mouse and Keyboard Events in Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx)